# Start a new page in a jQuery DataTable based on a cell's value

Tags: datatables

How to start a new page in a jQuery DataTable based on a cell's value?

Say i have two customers and the JSON result returns 50 records from database. I need the DataTable to show this record order by customer number separated, the table must start a new page and show customer num2 data.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and share any more details? Or any attempts?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for variable-length pagination, and I am not aware of anything which provides this in DataTables. Maybe someone else knows of such a thing. Instead, perhaps you can show every record (`"paging": false`), and filter the data based on customer ID.